# Android Share the text link use intent to LINE APP

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink

I have a question.

I need to use intent share the link text to LINE App in Android.

But I don't know how to share hyperlink  text to Line.

I know share the text to LINE message. below:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                            AppConfig.LINE_PACKAGE_NAME);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is share text but I want to set hyperlink");
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Have anyone know how to set text link(ex:link to www.google.com) use intent and share to LINE App in android?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you update the answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Just to write the hyper link text.

The Line app will auto generate the hyper link in there message panel.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void openLine(Context context, String number, String msg) {
    try {
        final String appName = "jp.naver.line.android";
        final boolean isAppInstalled = isAppAvailable(context, appName);
        if (isAppInstalled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("line://msg/text/" + msg));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Line not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR LINE", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Line not installed in your device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the hyper link to the end of the text:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is share text but I want to set hyperlink" + url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//intent.setData(Uri.parse("line://msg/text/" + msg)); // "line://" is deprecated
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://line.me/R/share?text=" + URLDecoder.decode(msg, "UTF-8")));
startActivity(intent);
```

the LINE Official recommond use `https://line.me/`

link: https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/messaging-api/using-line-url-scheme/#available-line-url-schemes